# $A=\bigg\{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_i}{5^{i}}\ :\ a_i\in\{0,1,2,3,4\} \bigg\} \subset \mathbb{R}.$ Then which of the following are true

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $$A=\bigg\{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_i}{5^{i}}\ :\  a_i\in\{0,1,2,3,4\} \bigg\} \subset \mathbb{R}.$$ Then which of the following are true:

a. $A$ is a finite set.

b. $A$ is countably infinite.

c. $A$ is uncountable but does not contain an open interval.

d. $A$ contains an open interval.

Comment: These are precisely the real numbers in $[0,1]$ written in base $5$.

Comment: @lulu What do you mean? i did not understand

Comment: Think about decimal form.  The decimal expansion of a real number in that interval is $\sum \frac {a_i}{10^i}$ where $a_i\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$.  This works for any base.

Comment: @YagnaPatel  What's disturbing, to me anyway, is that I answered that one as well.  Using more or less the same words.  No recollection of it at all.  Weird.